# Is there a better way to do it? ( Mongoid + TaggableWithContext )

Tags: ruby, mongodb, tags, sinatra, mongoid

is a few days I'm trying to learn how to use MongoID and I found myself faced with a problem:
there is a better way to do this?

```
  Group.find_by(name: params[:group]).subgroups.tags.each do |l|
   puts l
   puts Group.find_by(params[:group]).subgroups.tags_tagged_with(l).to_a
  end
```

I'm using MongoID in combo with [mongoid_taggable_with_context](https://github.com/lgs/mongoid_taggable_with_context)

The idea is to find all the tags belonging to a group, and for each of these the items with that tag.

Expected result (example):

Tag1:
 SubGroup2
 SubGroup3

Tag2:
 SubGroup1
 SubGroup2

etc.

Thanks for your patience